# Problem with multiple matches on same line in simple regular expression

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm having a very basic question about regular expressions. I am trying to match and replace URLs like these:

```
http://mydomain.com/image/13/imagetitle.html
```

For which I use the following expression:

```
/mydomain.com(.*)image\/(\d+)\/(.*).html/
```

This pattern works fine mostly, yet it does not work when multiple occurrences appear on the same line. So this works:

```
This is my own image: http://mydomain.com/image/13/imagetitle.html
```

When including multiple occurrences across lines it works as well:

```
This is my own image: http://mydomain.com/image/13/imagetitle.html
Yet I recommend this one as well: image: http://mydomain.com/image/15/imagetitle2.html
```

Both occurrences match and are replaced correctly. However, it only replaces the first match when there are two occurrences on the same line:

```
This is my own image: http://mydomain.com/image/13/imagetitle.html, yet I recommend this one as well: image: http://mydomain.com/image/15/imagetitle2.html
```

How can I make sure all matches are replaced, regardless of new lines?

Comment: Can you paste the code you're using to do the replace?

Comment: Actually, from the point of view of preg_replace() function, &lt;br/&gt is not a newline. Both examples are treated as single-line subject. It would be much clearer if you show your replacing code.

Comment: @Kel: I'm pretty sure the actual text has a newline at that spot, but the OP changed it to `<br/>` in the mistaken assumption that the newline would get normalized to a space when he posted the question.  As you pointed out, if there really were a `<br/>` there, he wouldn't be having this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't get the problem either. But just judging from the regex, your issue is likely to be the greediness.

`(.*)` matches as much as it can. It will catch two URLs at once, if they are on the same line. Typically you therefore want to use `(.*?)` instead, or apply the ungreediness `/U` flag.

But in your case I'd advise simply making the match more specific:

```
/mydomain.com(\S*)image\/(\d+)\/(\S*).html/
```

Here the `\S` will only match anything that isn't whitespace, because that's most certainly where URLs should be broken up. As alternative you could use a more specific character class like `([\w/.?&#%=-]*)` instead of `.*?` there.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly! It indeed was a greediness problem, I used the 'specific match' full rule exactly like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is working. I had tested it by the foll code:

```
$data = "This1 is my own image: http://mydomain.com/image/13/imagetitle.html, yet I recommend this one as well: image: http://mydomain.com/image/15/imagetitle2.html
This2 is my own image: http://mydomain.com/image/13/imagetitle.html, yet I recommend this one as well: image: http://mydomain.com/image/15/imagetitle2.html
This3 is my own image: http://mydomain.com/image/13/imagetitle.html, yet I recommend this one as well: image: http://mydomain.com/image/15/imagetitle2.html
This4 is my own image: http://mydomain.com/image/13/imagetitle.html, yet I recommend this one as well: image: http://mydomain.com/image/15/imagetitle2.html
";
echo preg_replace('/mydomain.com(.*)image\/(\d+)\/(.*).html/', 'replaced one', $data);
```